# android studio : linux, windows, and poor performances

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, mono

I am starting an Android application. I am very comfortable with .NET/Mono/Visual-Studio, and all my development environment runs under Windows. I installed Android Studio on my laptop (Windows 8.1). When opening a project template, Android Studio took a fews minutes indexing files (with lags), and then Gradle took 3 minutes to build the "empty" project. Now, Android Studio is "scanning files to index" (it seems a task related to the file system ?)... I disabled the "Security Center" service but things are the same. The emulator first start occurs within minutes... (I have acceptable perfs with Visual-Studio)

- Do you think Android Studio could have better performances under Linux (which distro ?), as it seems it commits a lot of operations that are related to the file system ? I have read that a Ramdisk could improve the situation.
- Could you please advise me some good readings to start Android development (blogs, books...) ?

Comment: (got -1 5s seconds after posting... could you please be more precise, or are you just trolling ?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android studio is best for u..there is android studio setup available for Linux,Mac and windows.And for your  preparation download androidcookbook pdf.